# Why cannot I resize?

Tags: python, image-processing

```
def create_data_matrix_from_video(clip, k=5, scale=50):
    return np.vstack([scipy.misc.imresize(rgb2gray(clip.get_frame(i/float(k))).astype(int), 
                      scale).flatten() for i in range(k * int(clip.duration))]).T
def rgb2gray(rgb):
    return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])

scale = 25   # Adjust scale to change resolution of image
dims = (int(240 * (scale/100)), int(320 * (scale/100)))

M = create_data_matrix_from_video(video, 100, scale)

print(dims, M.shape)

plt.imshow(np.reshape(M[:,140], dims), cmap='gray');
```

Error:

```
cannot reshape array of size 6336 into shape (60,80)
```

here I am having a problem with my output.

Comment: You've written the answer: `6336 into shape (60,80)`. Because _60 x 80 != 6336_ you can't reshape it

Comment: Can't I resize 6336 to 4800?
How can I able to solve this?

Comment: No, you physically can't. _Reshaping_ is a changing of array's shape using permutations of elements. What do you want to do?

Comment: what I am trying to do is BackgroundRemoval and I have got a video and I am just trying to get a shot from it and display it.

Comment: Okay. What do you want to do with image? Do you want to compress it?

Comment: No, it is important to get the image first so that I can further move on SVD.

Comment: I need that to be shaped in order to use the image. what can I do now?

Comment: When you reshape, you end up with exactly the same pixels and same number of pixels but organised differently. When you resize, you get a different number of pixels.

Comment: what would be my solution?

Comment: It looks to me like you want to end up with a different number of pixels from the number you started with, correct? So you need to resize, not reshape.

Comment: Yes. But I'm having a problem with resizing too.